# Argument to show View bounds in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview

I remember using an argument which was set in Edit Scheme -> Run -> Arguments which would display the view borders in yellow color.

Could not find any references to it, may be I am looking for wrong term, could some one help ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A little late to the party, but I believe the run argument you're looking for is

`-UIViewShowAlignmentRects YES`

Comment: Yep thats what I was looking for ! Found it later on :)

Answer (score 9):

There is an auto layout specific method described in [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/DebuggingTricksandTips.html) (described in the "Visualizing Views and Constraints" section). Start the app in the Simulator, go back to Xcode and select Debug -> View Debugging -> Show Alignment Rectangles.

Comment: That helps, thanks for that, but are you aware of the run time argument ?

Comment: @GoodSp33d I'm not aware of anything like this. You could probably write a cateogry on `UIView` that does that, but as far as I know there is nothing builtin for that.